# Filter data and adapt mean value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to filter an excel data list by one feature (part number) and then, when I deselect one part have it not be included into the calculation of e.g. the mean value. However the mean will stay the same, because it says `=MITTELWERT(B5:B14)` in the function line.

[image]

Does anybody have an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use subtotal to do this :

```
=SUBTOTAL(101, B5:B14)
```

You can use sub total for many other functions also, by replacing the 101 with any of the below:

```
Function    Include hidden  Ignore hidden
AVERAGE     1               101
COUNT       2               102
COUNTA      3               103
MAX         4               104
MIN         5               105
PRODUCT     6               106
STDEV       7               107
STDEVP      8               108
SUM         9               109
VAR         10              110
VARP        11              111
```

**Im not 100% sure but the German equivalent may be =TEILERGEBNIS ??**

Comment: Just to be clear for the OP, =SUBTOTAL(1,...) would do the required job here. As you show in the list of "subfunctions", 101 will ignore manually hidden rows as well as those that are filtered out. So 101 will work, but so would 1. Thought it might be useful to clarify for someone using a non-English version where the distinction between "hidden" and "not visible because of a filter" might be less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

`AGGREGATE()` using function #1 (Average) and option 5 (do not include hidden rows), or options 1, 3, or 7 (they ignore more things than just hidden rows) will also do the job:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,,A1:A9)    (for example)
```

because the function's code considers rows that are filtered out to be hidden in the same way that formally "hidden" rows are hidden.

An advantage though, to using `SUBTOTAL()`, is that there are other functions that can be told to ignore any `SUBTOTAL()` cells found in the range they are told to operate upon. `AGGREGATE()` will do that for itself, and for `SUBTOTAL()` but I am not aware, offhand, of any other functions that can be told to ignore `AGGREGATE()` functions in their operating ranges. If that would be any kind of concern, be sure to use `SUBTOTAL()`.

If of interest, the German version name for the `AGGREGATE()` function is `AGGREGAT`. And for `SUBTOTAL`, it is `TEILERGEBNIS`, just as `PeterH` shows. A useful website for this is:

https://www.excelfunctions.eu/

(For now anyway. Web pages do come and go.)